# dictionary from csv file

Tags: python, loops, csv, dictionary

So I have a csv file in the format:

- `a.year` is all the years
- `a.category` is all the categories
- etc

There can be more or fewerthan four columns.

```
a.year,a.category,a.actor,a.title
2010,Actor-Leading Role,Colin Firth,The King's Speech
2010,Actor-Supporting Role,Christian Bale,The Fighter
2010,Actress-Leading Role,Natalie Portman,Black Swan
2010,Actress-Supporting Role,Melissa Leo,The Fighter
2009,Actor-Leading Role,Jeff Bridges,Crazy Heart
```

How would I make a dictionary that has keys as the headers and all the values below that key as a a list mapping to that key. Something like:

```
{a.year:['2010', '2010', '2010', '2010', '2009'], 
 ... and so on}
```

for all the keys and values. Any ideas how to go about this?

So far I have tried to loop through the lines using a for loop but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You said: *So far I have tried to loop through the lines using a for loop...*, so show us what you tried and explain how it didn't work.

Comment: use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Comment: What does csv.dictreader do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this--- Open the file, map the column as the value to the header:

```
f = open("data.csv","r")
lines = list(map(lambda x: x.split(","),f.readlines())
f.close()

dictionary = {}
for i in range(len(lines[0])): 
    dictionary[lines[0][i]] = list(map(lambda x:lines[x][i], range(1,len(lines))))
```

Comment: The issue you may want to solve is that the types of everything will be a string. You may want to cast the values appropriately if you know which column should be a string or an int.